# Centos Disk LVM Extension

Tags: centos, vmware

I am having a problem with a VMWare VM which Centos7 is installed in it.

lsblk command gives something like below

[image]

df -h gives this

[image]

I am trying to extend root lvm to the partition but I am not able to do it no matter what I tried.

I tried fdisk /dev/sda to create a new partition and extend lvm to this partition but fdisk is getting stuck after partition number.

[image]

Some other useful commands give these results just in case they are helpful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your screenshot, your sda2 partition is 199G, sda1 takes 1G, your sda total size is 200G, you cannot make new partition from sda, that's why it stuck there;
and to resolve your issue I provide two options for you to refer,but before operation please make sure you back up all your important data or vm files.

**Option 1:** this one is just my thoughts,unverified:
from your vgs and pvs, you can see your sda2 only contributes <29G to whole VG(centos), so very simple way of extending your /root is:

> 1) `pvresize /dev/sda2`
>
> > ,after execute, pls run pvs to check whether the pv size increased, if not, stop here
>
> 2) `vgextend centos /dev/sda2`
>
> > ,after execute,pls check your vgs, see whether the size increased, if so go on to the next
>
> 3) `lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/mapper/centos-root`
>
> > ,after this, check lvs, if the root size not increased, go on
>
> 4) try:
>
> > `xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/centos-root`
> >     or
> >     `resize2fs /dev/mapper/centos-root`

**Option 2:** best practice is to use pvmove, this is strongly recommended for product environment, you can learn from
https://askubuntu.com/questions/161279/how-do-i-move-my-lvm-250-gb-root-partition-to-a-new-120gb-hard-disk

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your post. I have tried first command but I got this message.  Can't open /dev/sda2 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?

Comment: It is already mounted and I am using it. It has data. I do not know what I am missing.

Comment: first of all, make sure you back up all the data or your vms, then, you can try pvresize /dev/sda2 , and run pvs to check whether it works, if the pv size increased to the full size, then you may continue what I suggested previously

Comment: Hi. thanks a lot for your help. I have tried pvresize /dev/sda2 and this made a change. but vgextend centos /dev/sda2 did not work. I will add new screenshots.

Comment: in this case, you can just skip step 2), and try 3) and 4)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just skipped step 2 and executed 3 and 4. They worked like a charm. Now I have extended volume. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have executed pvresize /dev/sda2 command and after this I got pvs like below.

[image]

After this, I tried to execute vgextend centos /dev/sda2 but I got this error.

[image]

However vgs and vgdisplay centos commands are giving something different than before like below.

[image]